# Ruby on Rails 4.2 enum attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm trying to use new Enum type, everything works well except one issue. When writing functional tests I usually use structure:

```
order = Order.new(o_status: :one)
post :create, order: order.attributes

# Error message:
# ArgumentError: '0' is not a valid o_status
```

It's ok as long as I don't have Enum attribute. The problem with enums is that instead of String value `.attributes` returns it's Integer value which can't be posted as enum attribute value.

In above example model can look like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum o_status: [:one, :two]
end
```

I figured out that when I do:

```
order = Order.new(o_status: :one)
atts = order.attributes
atts[:o_status] = "one" # it must be string "one" not symbol or integer 0
post :create, order: order.attributes
```

It will work OK.

Is it normal or there is some better solution?

#### EDIT:

The only workaround which I found looks like this:

```
order = { o_status: :one.to_s }
post :create, order: order
```

- pros: It is short and neat
- cons: I cannot validate order with `order.valid?` before sending with post

This doesn't solve issue with `order.attributes` when there is Enum inside.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`Enum` documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

> You can set the default value from the database declaration, like:

```
create_table :conversations do |t|
  t.column :status, :integer, default: 0
end
```

> Good practice is to let the first declared status be the default.

Best to follow that advice and avoid setting a value for an enum as part of create. Having a default value for a column does work in tests as well.

Comment: OK, thanks. This is a good point. But to be truth I was hoping to find some clever "Rails way" of writing code in question.